# How can I get the iPhone to "forget" certain words?

Tags: iphone, auto-complete

The auto-complete features can be nice, but somewhere along the line my iPhone has learned some questionable language.  How can I get the iPhone to "forget" certain words from its auto-complete settings / dictionary?

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19560/218).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like [it used to be possible](http://iostips.net/add-custom-words-ios-dictionary-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch/) to manually edit the user dictionary, but unfortunately it isn't anymore.

Just a guess, but perhaps you can have it forget them the same way it learned them — when it suggests the word, try tapping on the small [x] next to the suggestion. If you do this a few times it may "forget" the word.

[image]

You can reset the dictionary entirely by going to Settings > General > Reset:

[image]

Comment: Aw, you beat me by 6 seconds, *and with a screenshot!* I bow to your superior knowledge and skills.

Comment: You beat me, too.

Comment: I thought that tapping the little x by the word just meant "go away, don't replace this now".  ?

Comment: @KatieK: It does, but if you do it enough times I believe it learns not to offer the suggestion anymore.

Comment: Can anyone verify that it does?

Comment: Without supporting documentation or access to the code, no. But it may be provable empirically - try it out.

Answer (score 8):

I opened notes, typed the word I wanted and when the incorrect autocorrect showed I pressed the cross. I pressed space bar and repeated the process 8 times. On the 9th time the incorrect suggestion stopped showing. Now it doesn't suggest the incorrect word anywhere!

Answer (score 7):

Go to Settings--General--Keyboard--Add New Shortcut

Put the CORRECT word in the phrase spot and the misspelled word in Shortcut spot.  Every time you type the word the phone wants to autocorrect with the misspelled word, it will automatically default to the CORRECT spelling!  It doesn't remove the word from the dictionary, but it beats the phone at its own game!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to reset the keyboard dictionary:

*Settings* → *General* → *Reset* → *Reset Keyboard Dictionary*

Answer (score 4):

You can either erase all learned words by going to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Keyboard Dictionary, or you can have your iPhone automatically censor out bad language that you type. To do the latter, go to `Settings > General > Keyboard > Edit`. You can then set a "censor" for bad language. What you could do is create a new shortcut for when you type the Phrase "cheese", it'll automatically Shortcut to "ch***e."

Answer (score 2):

Short of a reset (as the other answers mentioned) or jail breaking, you can't :-(

There are a lot of tips to tuning it [in this GigaOm article](http://gigaom.com/apple/ios-quick-tip-mastering-the-auto-correct-dictionary/) (including the name of the file to edit if you do jailbreak).

You can tune it by typing a word and insisting it is correct, you can add a word manually Through a somewhat hidden feature in international keyboard settings, but annoyingly the only way to make it forget is to forget everything.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, there's also this option which will make it not replace *any* words:

**Turn off Auto-Correction:**

1. Launch the **Settings** app
2. Go to **General > Keyboard**
3. Turn off **Auto-Correction**

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this. Opened notes, and commenced meeting in a word.  Words I do not want appear on the banner above the keyboard. Just press and hold those words and you will be invited to remove the word from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where every time I typed the name "Larissa" it would capitalize it to "LARISSA". No matter how many times I hit the "X" next to the suggestion, the thing just would not go away.

I discovered that I had a contact in my address book with the surname "LARISSA" (capitalized), and it was using this contact to make the correction automatically. As soon as I adjusted the contact, it no longer forced this capitalization.

It's possibly a rare case, but hope it helps someone else out there.

*(Using iOS 9.3)*

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of iOS, this process has changed. To remove a specific incorrect autocorrect suggestion, long-click on the incorrect suggestion, click "Stop suggesting", then--this is important--click the right suggestion. From my testing it appears as though the incorrect suggestion is not actually removed until you tell it the correct suggestion.

[image: Screenshot showing incorrect default autocorrect suggestion]
[image: Screenshot after long-click showing stop suggesting text]
[image: Screenshot after removing incorrect suggestion showing correct suggestion.]

Comment: This is a feature of the Google keyboard/Gboard, not of iOS's default keyboard. (Though I wish it was.)

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard was capitalising a name. I tried resetting the keyboard in settings but that didn’t work. Found it capitalised in contacts. As soon as I corrected it in contacts it stopped suggesting it.

Comment: This answer does not seem to differ from Simon East‘s, does it?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a keyboard shortcut. Settings>General>Keybord>Text Replacement. This may work for a word or phrase you use frequently.  This may help in reprogramming the dictionary. It's an indirect way to edit the spell check function.

Answer (score -1):

add another English keyboard (e.g Canada / UK) and voilá